# Biased Coin Flip With User inputs

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function coinFlip() {
      return (Math.random() < 0.3) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';
    }

    var flipamount = 100;
    var countHeads = 0;
    var countTails = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < flipamount; i++) {
      if (coinFlip() === 'Heads') {
        countHeads++;
        //document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML = "Heads";
      } else {
        countTails++;
        //document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML = "Tails";
      }
    }

    // coinFlip();

    //alert("Heads appear "+(countHeads/howManyTimes)*100+"% of the time"); //Code that works

    alert("Heads appears " + countHeads + ", Tails appears " + countTails); //Code that works
  </script>

</head>

<button type="button" onclick="coinFlip()" id="Coin">CLICK ME</button>
<p>
</p>

</html>
```

So I need to make a biased coin flipper. So far, I've managed to make the coin more biased towards tails or heads, but now I need to be able to make some of these variables editable in HTML. I have to be able to allow the user to change the probability at will, as well as be able to control how many times the user flips the coin.

I also can't make the button work, I can only make the results appear using alert in my script. Kind of stuck at the moment and would appreciate any assistance. I'm also not too experienced in Javascript.

Comment: @Mellow, What are the variables needs to be declared by user?? Do you want an input box in HTML to allow user to enter those values?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan The user needs to be able to declare the probability which is currently set to 0.3, but that needs to be editable now. As well as the flipamount. The user needs to be able to choose how many times the coin is flipped and the overall results from it. So yes, I'd want to get input boxes in HTML to allow the user to enter those values.

Comment: @Mellow, I have made changes in your code and you can look it up here https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/BaaGBvv

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thank you! Glad to see some more different solutions. I haven't used querySelector before so I'll look into it to see what it does.

Comment: @Mellow, query selector is one of the query methods and here as you don't have any ```id``` for ```p``` tag, I have used selection using query selector.. Also I would like to know from you whether this is you expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty raw and doesn't have any error handling in it, but should answer your original question. It has inputs for probability and for number of flips. After each set of flips you keep a running total of how many heads and tails there are.

I added a function to run after button press and gave the `<p>` element an ID to be able to write the results directly into it.

```js
//set both heads and tails to zero 
var countHeads = 0;
var countTails = 0;
//ternary function to decide between heads or tails
function coinFlip(param) {
 return (Math.random() < param) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';
}

function Execute() {
    //takes the value of the number input
 var flipamount = Number(document.getElementById("numb").value);
    for (var i = 0; i < flipamount; i++) {
    //takes the value of the probability input to use in the coinFilp function
   if (coinFlip(Number(document.getElementById("prob").value)) === 'Heads') {
        //add one to heads if heads comes up
     countHeads++;
    } else {
        //add one to tails if tails comes up
     countTails++;
    }
  }
  //write result to the paragraph
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Heads appears " + countHeads + ", Tails appears " + countTails;
}
```

```html
Probability: <input id="prob" type="number" size="3" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" /><br />
Number Flips: <input id="numb" type="number" size="3" min="10" max="100" step="10" value="50" /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="Execute()" id="Coin">CLICK ME</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I see, interesting take on the solution. Currently still trying to interpret it but its definitely working. I was wondering though, what type of change would I need to make to enable the total number of flips to reset whenever I press the button again?

Comment: You could reset the two variables, countHeads and countTails to be 0 at the top of the Execute function.Personally, I'd have a separate reset button. I've added some comments to the code.

Answer (score 2):

- Added An Id to your button and attached an event
- Move the script to be declared after the HTML DOM
- ADDED a function to do the alert
- Added Two Event Listeners
- Added two form element for adjustable value's
  -

```js
function coinFlip() {
 let InputElem = document.getElementById('textBoxRatio').value;

            return (Math.random() < InputElem) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';

        }

           

function go()
    {
    //Get Input

     var howManyTimes=  document.getElementById('textBoxSpin').value;
     var countHeads=0;
     var countTails=0;
                for (var i=0; i<howManyTimes;i++){
                    if (coinFlip()==='Heads'){
                         countHeads++;                   
                     } 
                     else 
                     {
                        countTails++;
                     }

            }
     //  alert("Heads appears " + countHeads + ", Tails appears " + countTails); 
     let I =   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="Heads appears " + countHeads + ", Tails appears " + countTails;
    }
         //Add Event Listener
          var t = document.getElementById('NewId');
          t.addEventListener("click", coinFlip);
          t.addEventListener("click", go);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
<body>

<label>Ratio :</label >
<input id='textBoxRatio' type ='text'><br>
<label>Spin Count :</label >
<input id='textBoxSpin' type ='text'><br>
<button id='NewId' type="button"  id="Coin">CLICK ME</button>

    <p id='result'>
    </p>
<!-- SCRIPT HERE !-->

</body>


</html>
```

Just remember to call your script after the HTML button Tag

Comment: I see, thank you for this. It's giving me some clarification and some ways I can improve on what I'm trying to accomplish. Also interesting to see the similarities between your solution and perspective of the problem and some of the other responders/users. Appreciate the assistance!